# 2.8+ Python: Get UV Loops

Tags: python, uv, loop

I want to get UV Loops lists of selected UV points. UV Loops should be sorted so that I could Align them. Is it possible?
https://i.imgur.com/N87YT4u
[image].png

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post